# Chart of 3 variables in R with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

So i have a daframe like that in R

| Client | Car | Job | Freq (%) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Woman | Mercedes AMG | Doctor | 33 |
| Man | BMW M Series | Lawyer | 78 |

I'd like to draw a chart with ggplot2 for the frequencies, taking into account Client, Car and Job, so that i can show the % of woman driving a mercedes AMG while they're doctor (for instance) and that's for all of my observations. I prefer barchat but any kind of chart can be made, i like original stuff by the way.

I'm used to 2 variables in ggplot2 and i have error messages or simply no output when i try.

Thanks !

**CODE I TRIED**

```
tryy <- ggplot(gc,aes(x = Job ,y = Freq(%))) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = c(Client, Car)),stat = "identity",position = "dodge")+ labs(title = "aa", x = "bb", y = "cc") +
  labs(title = "aa", x="bb",y="cc",fill="Client", size=12) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face="bold", color="#993333",size=12, angle=17),
        axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold", color="#993333",size=12, angle=90))+
  theme(axis.title=element_text(size=14,face="bold"))+
  geom_text(aes(label = Freq), position=position_dodge(width=1), vjust=-0.25,size=5)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#054C70","#05C3DE","Red"))

print(tryy)
```

As you can see, my code is very wrong, i new using ggplot2 and i don't really understand how to proceed.

Comment: (a) Please show the code you tried in your best attempt, along with the error message. (b) Please describe more about the chart your want. I can imagine  `Freq` on the y-axis. Perhaps `Car` on the x-axis, maybe the fill color for the `Client`, how do you want to display `Job` to make it distiguishable from the other bars? Maybe facets? If you're not sure, perhaps you can sketch the graph you want to make on a whiteboard or something.

Comment: *"I like original stuff"* ... what does that mean?

Comment: @GregorThomas I added the code

Comment: @r2evans Sorry what i meant is that i'm really open to all kind of data viz, not only simple histograms and so on !

Comment: @GregorThomas it's the first time i have to draw this kind of chart so whatever the design i guess i don't have special preferences. However, as it's destined to the public it should be understandable by everyone for sure. But yeah the frequency should be in the y axis !

Comment: It's on you to figure out what graph you want. Tell us what you want, and we can help you with the code to create it. *"whatever the design i guess i don't have special preferences"* isn't a clear coding question, and isn't on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @GregorThomas From what i saw on Google Images, the facets seem indeed the best option. I think about : Car facets ; y-axis as Freq ; Job as x-axis and the bar filled with Client.

Answer (score 1):

It worked like that !

```
try <- ggplot(gc,aes(x =Job ,y = Freq(%))) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Client),stat = "identity",position = "dodge")+ labs(title = "aa", x = "bb", y = "cc") +
  labs(title = "aa", x="bb",y="cc",fill="Client", size=12) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face="bold", color="#993333",size=12, angle=17),
        axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold", color="#993333",size=12, angle=90))+
  theme(axis.title=element_text(size=14,face="bold"))+
  geom_text(aes(label = Freq(%), group=Client), position=position_dodge(width=1), vjust=-0.25,size=5)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#054C70","#05C3DE"))

try <- try + facet_wrap( ~ gc$Car, ncol=2)

print(try)

ggsave(try, filename="try.png",dpi = 300, height = 20, width = 30, units = "cm" )
```